# Какой знак препинания нужно употребить?

Tags: пунктуация

*Из окна я не могла рассмотреть(,) синички или воробьи клевали ранетки*.

Я не могла рассмотреть (что?)... синички или воробьи клевали...
Два предложения. 
Нужна запятая или другой знак?

Answer (score 2):

Это СПП, между основной частью *из окна я не могла рассмотреть* и придаточной частью *синички или воробьи клевали ранетки* **нужна запятая**.

Comment: Спасибо. Будем повторять правила про СПП)